# Are those measures unique?

Tags: measure-theory

Question goes:

Assume that $\mu_1,\mu_2,\nu_1,\nu_2$ are measures on $\sigma$-algebra $M$. Such that $\mu_1-\mu_2=\nu_1-\nu_2$. Does it imply that $\mu_1=\nu_1 \land \mu_2=\nu_2$?

Point is, professor said they are not unique, but, after thinking a bit and looking for the answer on the internet, all I found is that Jordan signed measure decomposition is, in fact, unique. Now, I'm not sure if my prof. made a mistake saying that or, in fact, he is right and I got to think about it some more.

Edit:( One of those measures is finite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not. For example, take any two finite measures $\mu\ne \nu$. Then $\mu-\mu = \nu-\nu$.

In Jordan signed measure decomposition, there are extra conditions and then such decomposition indeed becomes unique.

Comment: What if only one of those measures is finite, or none of them is?

Comment: Same argument works. But if both measures are infinite, you have to be careful that you don't get something like infinity minus infinity.